# Checking for available disk space in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, diskspace

I have implemented the following code:

1. Download a zip file using RNFS.downloadFile()
2. Unzip the file using ZipArchive.unzip()
3. Delete the zip file using RNFS.unlink()

I can send info from the server indicating how big the zip file is and how big the unpacked directory is. However, how can I detect if there is enough space on the device to download and unzip the file? I assume once I figure this out I can just do a check like this:

```
if (free_space_on_device > zip_size + unpacked_size){
   proceed with steps 1 through 3 (listed above)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not realize that RNFS had a function called getFSInfo. With that knowledge, I can just issue the following command:

```
RNFS.getFSInfo()
.then ((info) => {
   console.log("Free Space is" + info.freeSpace + "Bytes")
   console.log("Free Space is" + info.freeSpace / 1024 + "KB")
})
```

Comment: `RNFS.getFSInfo` Doesn't take an argument : https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#getfsinfo-promisefsinforesult It seems that it returns info only for the main storage.

Comment: @Marc_Alx Right you are. Thank you for that information!

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using [`react-native-fetch-blob`](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-fetch-blob) and not `react-native-fs` this is the function you are looking for:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.df().then( response => {
  console.log('Free space in bytes: ' + response.free);
  console.log('Total space in bytes: ' + response.total);
} );
```

On Android, the response object looks like this:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.df().then( response => {
  console.log('External free space in bytes: ' + response.external_free);
  console.log('External total space in bytes: ' + response.external_total);
  console.log('Internal free space in bytes: ' + response.internal_free);
  console.log('Internal total space in bytes: ' + response.internal_total);
} );
```