# React Native / iOS - Check if CameraRoll Storage is Full

Tags: ios, react-native

Users who have little to no storage space in their camera roll aren't able to record a video in our app. Once they start recording a video and their storage fills up, our app crashes.

We are using react-native-camera to record video, but it looks like this might fall into the CameraRoll module in React Native itself.

Is there a way to detect how much storage a user has available on their phone? We'd like to give them a warning if they are low in storage before they record their video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799211/checking-for-available-disk-space-in-react-native) but I can't flag it as such since the answer isn't accepted.

You can use [react-native-fs's getFSInfo()](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#getfsinfo-promisefsinforesult) to get the `totalSpace` and `freeSpace`.